# Como fazer um loop em um intervalo de tempo de uma animação em JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animação

Eu tenho uma animação estilo Guitar Hero e eu gostaria de repetir a animação da nota verde caindo em um intervalo definido de tempo, porém não estou conseguindo...

http://jsfiddle.net/3Qs7D/1/

Comment: Já deu uma olhada em `setInterval`? [Documentação no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)

Comment: Já, porém ao tentar usar eu não obtive sucesso

Comment: @user8957, fico contente de ter ajudado. Se quiser pode colocar aqui, ou em nova pergunta, o código completo pois acho que pode optimizar e encurtar muito no seu código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa criar cópias/clones das notas para as poder voltar a fazer cair.
O que está a acontecer agora é que no fim da animação a `$('.nota_verde_cair')` é removida e não dá para voltar a usar...

**Aqui fica uma sugestão: http://jsfiddle.net/pvKt6/**

```
function newgame() {
    $("#comecar").hide();
    $("div.teclas").css("margin-right", "393px");
    $("div.teclas").css("float", "right");
    $("div.bgplay").css("opacity", "1.0");
    hover();


    setInterval(verde, 7000); // para repetir a animaçao

    function verde() {
        inicio;
        acertos = 0;
        var notaVerde = $('.nota_verde_cair').clone(); // criar um clone
        $('div.bgplay').append(notaVerde);             // inserí-lo no documento

        function testarAcerto(e) {
            if (e.which == 51 && Math.round(valorAtual) > 0) {
                notaVerde.remove(); // usar o clone em vez do original
                acertos++;
                $(document).bind("keyup");
            }
        }

        notaVerde.fadeTo(500, 1);   // usar o clone em vez do original
        // etc, usando sempre o clone
```